# If I add one fruit a day - which one?

Tags: fruits

I don't eat fast food and go to the gym. I try to eat healthily & sensibly.

I have noticed that I sometimes feel hungry/have an energy dip mid-afternoon.

I always have some granola bars in a desk drawer & will occasionally have one of those.

Should I eat a piece of fruit then, and, if so, whic?

Comment: As you can see, I am new here. Could  the downvoters please tell me why and I will try to improve the question? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. I'm afraid that this question is too broad, as there are so many arguments that could be made for so many different fruits. I'm going have to put this on-hold, but if you make it less broad, you can flag for reopening. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why stick to only one type of fruit? One day you have an apple and a guava the next. After all, each fruit has it's own set of benefits and they are all good for your health. No fruit is considered bad to consume right? And if you are only looking to fill up your energy meter and to satiate your mid-afternoon cravings, bananas are an excellent choice as they are high in calories and are very effective in eliminating hunger.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)